# c# to c++/cli Enum declaration

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums, c++-cli

I have looked several places, but can't seem to find quite what I'm looking for. I'm making a WPF app, using c++/cli to mess with the c# xmal. I have an interface where I declare whatever I want the xaml to see for DataContext that is in c#, but what I declared in my c# interface is implemented in my c++/cli file.

I'm trying to find a way to declare an enum in c# and then actually define what it is in the c++/cli, but I am having problems with it. (Whatever I declare in the c# interface requires an accessor, which might be part of the problem)

What I have tried so far is in the c# interface,

```
Enum Days { get; }
```

Then in the c++/cli

```
enum class days { Sun= 0, Mon, ...}
virtual property System::Enum^ Days
    { System::Enum^ get() { return days; } }
```

However on the return statement, it says, "type name is not allowed". I think that is because the System::Enum^ is supposed to be value from an enum, not the created enum type itself. Is there some kind of base class or something that all enum types inherit from, or any other way to do what I'm looking to do?

Comment: The C++11 language revision adopted `enum class` as well. So you actually declared an unmanaged enum type. It is not convertible to System::Enum. You must use prefix `public` or `private` to convince the compiler that you meant to declare a managed enum.  And you must return a value, not a type.  Since you appear to want to return a type, high odds that your approach is simply broken.  Your C# code can use the enum as well, declare it public.  Or the other way around.  Or maybe you need two assemblies.

Comment: I think it just doesn't work. I ended up defining my enum in my C# namespace, so then I could reference it in my c++/cli.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to find a way to declare an enum in c# and then actually define what it is in the c++/cli.

You can't declare a type in one assembly and define it in another. It doesn't work like that.

You can declare properties as type `Enum` in C#, and return any enum value, and that'll work. However, you need to return an enum *value*, not the name of an enum class.

```
System::Enum^ get() { return days::Monday; } // works
```

Or, you could declare a property where you inform the rest of the application of the enum *type* you're using. The rest of the application would use reflection to figure out which values are in the enumeration.

```
System::Type^ get() { return days::typeid; } // also works.
```